# What are some recommended day trips from New York City for outdoor activities?

Tags: hiking, new-york-city, day-trips, outdoor-activities, walking

I am specifically interested in walking/hiking/cycling rather than going to the beach or skiing.

Answer (score 6):

The Appalachian Trail is [a stop on the Metro North Railroad](http://www.wesi.net/at/index.html) on weekends.

Comment: Considering the available schedule from [Grand Central](http://as0.mta.info/mnr/schedules/sched_form.cfm) I'd make it a 2 day trip.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like biking around [Central Park](http://www.nycbikemaps.com/maps/central-park-map/).  Try [Bear Mountain](http://www.roberts-1.com/bikehudson/r/west/nyc_bm/).  There is a race there in the summer but I can't find the info now.

You can go to the [Poconos for hiking](http://www.800poconos.com/things-to-do/outdoor-adventure/hiking/), [Trail Biking](http://www.800poconos.com/things-to-do/outdoor-adventure/trail-biking/), Kayaking, Fishing.  [More on the Poconos here](http://www.roadtripusa.com/routes/appalachiantrail/pennsylvania/app_thepoconos.html).

There is also [Catskills](http://www.visitthecatskills.com/) but I wouldn't do it in one day.

Answer (score 2):

I once did a day trip from NYC to Princeton University, which is not that far away. I really went for the campus, which is really nice (when compared to the 1970s concrete bunkers of my Uni) and also for record shopping. But there are several [hiking trails](http://www.trails.com/trailfinder/browsebymap/?statecode=NJ&lat=40.35037&lon=-74.66099&z=11&a=HK) nearby. The Sourland Mountain ones look interesting. I haven't been around in New Jersey that much, but that part of it was actually quite nice.